# After updating to VS2019 16.9.1, xamarin android project no longer links

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

My Xamarin Android project builds fine with VS2019 16.7.12 but it gets this link error now that I've upgraded to VS2019 16.9.1:

```
7>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(300,5): 
error XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `System.Drawing`, referenced by `netstandard`. 
Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Drawing`, or remove the reference to `netstandard`.
========== Rebuild All: 5 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 skipped ==========
```

We have been building this project without issues since VS2015 so I'm not sure if this is a VS2019 bug or if something else is wrong.  None of the projects reference netstandard, at least not at the top level.  I'd rather not hack the project to add a direct reference to System.Drawing.dll in the Windows folder since that breaks the build for others on my team still running 16.7 VS2019.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: you can go to Visual studio **Help--Send Feedback--Report a Problem** to report this problem.

Comment: Maybe one of the projects in solution targets the platform that System.Drawing is not supporting